# Float variables being formatted incorrectly in C func from Python

Tags: python, mysql, c

I'm not sure if this is correct place to ask. But we use a python library called umysql. We're in the process of upgrading our python2 to python3, and thus have moved to umysql3.
umysql is a C/C++ mysql driver.

If you run this code:

```
import umysql3
import dsnparse

conn = umysql3.Connection()
conn.settimeout(1)
conn.connect(
    #connection details
)

conn.query('''
    select %s, %s, %s;
    ''', (51.4827, -3.1808, 123))
```

You will get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test-umysql.py", line 15,
>   in 
>       ''', (51.4827, -3.1808, 123)) umysql.SQLError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '\0\0\01\0\0, -\0\0\03\0\0, 123' at line 1")

I have no idea what is happening to the float variables, and I'm a bit out of my league inregards to python calling C funcs.
I was wondering if anyone could give me a pointer, or an idea to look into, about what is possibly happening here.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Without entering into the specifics of your library, it seems that you're using the wrong format specifier: floats are commonly specified with `%f`.

If it keeps failing, you might want to consider the **less secure** but clearer way of formatting the query yourself, before giving it to `umysql`.

```py
query = "select {:f}, {:f}, {:f}".format(51.4827, -3.1808, 123)
# 'select 51.482700, -3.180800, 123.000000'
```

**EDIT**:
A brief look into the unit tests gave no evidence of your escaping syntax being supported at all. Some tests do the escaping themselves (see [here](https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql/blob/f8703807c314e10188df7de97a53ace9c78943b7/tests/tests.py#L246))

```py
for i in range(10):
    self.assertEquals((1, 0), cnn.query("insert into tbltest (test_id, test_string) values (%d, 'test%d')" % (i, i)))
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid the less secure way. Not sure %f is possible in this. Similar to mysqldb-python. I think the expectation is each var represented by %s

Comment: @edit that is weird! definitly supports it lol. Otherwise the last 5-7 years our system has been lying to us

Comment: Here is a test showing how we use it : https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql/blob/f8703807c314e10188df7de97a53ace9c78943b7/tests/tests.py#L445